# Can't install pandas on SLES 12 SP1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip, suse, sles

I'm trying to install pandas on my python3 installation. Version is 3.4.6, which seems to be the most up to date for this OS. I installed python with:

zypper in python3

I run the command:

pip3 install pandas

It gives me back a log, here is the part where the error is referenced:

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -fstack-protector -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g -fwrapv -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF -fPIC -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c pandas/_libs/tslib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/_libs/tslib.o -Wno-unused-function
  gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-clash-protection’
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

---

Failed building wheel for pandas
  Running setup.py clean for pandas
Failed to build pandas
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Running setup.py install for pandas ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-xvndc9lz/pandas/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-nq8ffg3o/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

Now, I've already googled around, there is a an issue on pip's github which references this problem, but none of the solutions worked.

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5720

Solutions were updating gcc. Mine was initially at version 4.8 but i've already tried 4.9 and 5. Can't go higher than that because YAST is having trouble with dependencies and god know what else.

Any ideas? I think it must be something about the OS, because i've managed to install pandas in another machine, with another linux distro, same python, same gcc..

Answer (score 0):

There is a gcc7 in the "Toolchain Module". `SUSEconnect` and/or `YaST` will allow to enable this extra package repository.